# How to use awk command to get only three column and values from docker ps result

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

```
[centos@exe93-aws-mum:/exedge-volume/exedge]# docker ps | awk '{print $2,$5}'
ID CREATED
docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.9.1 minutes
gcr.io/ec2nf-256816/n3iwf-nwu:v2.0.0-992f54d minutes
gcr.io/ec2nf-256816/upf-ids:stg.misp-rule-integ-cb264cc minutes
gcr.io/ec2nf-256816/upf-fpm:at.r2.3.2 minutes
gcr.io/ec2nf-256816/upf-dns:v2.0.0-b4057d4 minutes
redis minutes
gcr.io/ec2nf-256816/exe-health:at.r2.3.1 minutes
prom/alertmanager:latest 5
prom/prometheus:latest 5
prom/node-exporter:latest 5
95713166e223 4
3f822532aac3 weeks
```

''the values are not getting from specific column and total values are also not getting in same.
Could you please help me in this. Thanks advance!''

Comment: Can you show the result you would like to see?

Comment: This is not going to work for you. The `docker ps` output is irregular, for example some column values sometimes have spaces and others do not, so you're not going to be successful splitting on whitespace. You might consider `docker ps --format` which generates table output.

Comment: yes its correct sometime i'm  getting the values from other columns as well

Comment: is it possible get the values of " status, image, container name " from docker-compose ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use awk, use the docker-ps format flag:

```
docker ps --format "{{.Image}}: {{.RunningFor}} {{.Names}}"
```

You can also format the output into json using jq.

```
 docker ps --format "{ \"image\": \"{{.Image}}:\", \"Running\": \"{{.RunningFor}}\", \"Names\": \"{{.Names}}\" }" | jq -r
```

Comment: working but  i need get container name as well .. How can I achieve this..?

Comment: I've amended the solution

Comment: This is a solution, but it does not answer the question.